# how do I convert a String like {key1=value1, key2=value2} into a json String or Jsonobject?

Tags: java

such like this:

```
{aliSerialNumber=111111, pubmsCode=null, orderNumber=111, orderId=null, queryNo=null, msgId=null, consNo=null, userId=null, instId=null, companyId=null, appId=null, extendMap=null, pageSource=null, aliStatus=null}
```

convert into like this:

```
{"aliSerialNumber":"111111" ...}
```

is there any utils in Java I can use?

ps:The String is not a println result, it is from log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdpRW.png)

Comment: Jackson has an ObjectMapper that should be able to do this for you. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: I would parse the string into a HashMap and then convert it to json.

Comment: @Unknown It's a string, not a hashmap

Comment: @Unknown "like" as in "for example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for this.

here is sample test code to convert your string into *Gson* based `JsonObject` and verify if converted json is valid. you can use the relative following code.

```
@Test
public void checkJson() {
    String json = "{aliSerialNumber=111111, pubmsCode=null, orderNumber=111, orderId=null, queryNo=null, msgId=null, consNo=null, userId=null, instId=null, companyId=null, appId=null, extendMap=null, pageSource=null, aliStatus=null}";
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
    assertNotNull(jsonObject);
    assertEquals(jsonObject.get("aliSerialNumber").getAsInt(),111111);
    System.out.print(jsonObject.get("aliSerialNumber"));
}
```

returns true.

further read about gson [here](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: Glad it solved your problem, please give a thumbs  up so others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without any utils like:

```
String str = "{aliSerialNumber=111111, pubmsCode=null, orderNumber=111, orderId=null, queryNo=null, msgId=null, consNo=null, userId=null, instId=null, companyId=null, appId=null, extendMap=null, pageSource=null, aliStatus=null}";
str = str.replace("{", "");
str = str.replace("}", "");

String[] temp = str.split(",");
String json = "{";

for (String s : temp)
{
    String key = s.split("=")[0].trim();
    String val = s.split("=")[1].trim();

    json += "\"" + key + "\":";
    json += "\"" + val + "\", ";
}

json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 2);
json += "}";

System.out.println(json);
```

Result is this (valid JSON):

```
{"aliSerialNumber":"111111", "pubmsCode":"null", "orderNumber":"111", "orderId":"null", "queryNo":"null", "msgId":"null", "consNo":"null", "userId":"null", "instId":"null", "companyId":"null", "appId":"null", "extendMap":"null", "pageSource":"null", "aliStatus":"null"}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have quotes around the keys?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There are, see the printed JSON.

Comment: Excellent, now I see it in the code to. But now I wonder if it is ok for values, will "null" be handled correct?

Comment: thanks,but it would be no use when the String is just like this:{platform=WEB, extend_map=8510011370059, order_amt=200.00, page_source=MINI_PRODUCT, query_no=8510011370059, client_ip=223.104.145.164, pubms_code=NTJIANGSU, pro_infos=[{"pro_price":"200.00","activities":{},"order_type":"02","pro_det_id":623,"pro_num":1,"pro_id":"1903061016064145","pro_period":"","pro_code":"-1"}], rcvbl_det={}, msg_id=15525287164017741445526916641234, pay_mode=1, user_id=2088702340651417, app_id=2019022763445292, cons_no=8510011370059, method=create.order, call_source=MINI_APP}

Comment: Well, that is a different question. I made a solution to your original post.